# PDE - Derivations of formulas for Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve PDE on domain $\Omega= [0,L_x]\times [0,L_y]$ by using finite difference method. Unknown function is $C=C(t,x,y)$. Following conditions are given: north $C=0$, west $C=f(y)$, south $\dfrac{\partial C}{\partial y}=0$ and east $\dfrac{\partial C}{\partial x}=0$. I made difference scheme for internal nodes and for points associated with $(i,j)$ scheme includes $(i-1,j),(i+1,j),(i,j),(i,j-1)$ and $(i,j+1)$.

How can i derive formula for corners, specifically down left corner  associated with (1,1)?
For down right corner I replaced "out of bound node" ($n_x+1,1)$ with p$(n_x-1,1)$ and "out of bound node" $(n_x,0)$ with $(n_x,2).$ Situations where conditions with partial derivative meet i know how to deal with, but what to corners where standard condition meet with partial derivate condition? Do i create two equation associated with that node or?
Maybe it is usual that on  mentioned corners   we prioritize standard simple conditon and ignore condition with partial derivative?

Comment: Once you have all other points (except from the corners) can't you just find the values on the corners using the boundary condition?

Comment: That's not how it works. There are $n_x\cdot n_y$ unknown variables i.e. values of $C$ at   grid. For  solving that I need to create $n_x\cdot n_y$ equations. By now i created $n_x\cdot n_y-2$ and I am suspicious in downleft corner where  $\partial C/\partial y=0$  and $C=f(y)$. Same problem with upright corner

Comment: You do not need equations for the nodes on the part of the boundary where you have Dirichlet boundary condition (west in your case), since you are already given the value there. The down lest node is one of them, the value there is f(0).